# Can't "go to declaration" in *.ashx files (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When I open *.ashx files in Visual Studio, I don't have the helpful "Go to Declaration" context menu when right-clicking on a function.

How can I restore this functionality (this is a new install)?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Hey -- good to know, Hunter -- what I found in the meantime was similar, but (imo) easier. If hover over a function or variable, you can just hold down CTRL and then click. It'll take you where you want to go. Thanks for the other approach . .

Answer (score 0):

Click on the text you want to go to and key **F12** if it's not showing up for you.

Much like Windows Operation Systems need to reboot when things start breaking down, Studio sometimes needs a restart if that doesn't work.

Obviously this doesn't get your menu item back, but it's a fix that you might prefer over selecting that from the right-click mouse menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark since I do not work with ASP-related stuff.

### Short Answer

If your *.ashx files belong to a project, open the project first.

### Longer Answer

Most of my work in Visual Studio 2008 is with C++ and C# code.  If I open a .cpp file or .cs file in VS2008 independent of the project it belongs to, VS2008 doesn't give me the *Go To Declaration* context menu either.  When I open files independent of the project they belong to, VS2008 (or any Visual Studio version for that matter) is little more than a glorified editor.  To get the benefit of *Go To Declaration* and other features, e.g., Intellisense, I have to first open the project and then open the file from within VS2008.

### Alternate Answer

If you are already doing this, you might try deleting the .suo file in your project directory and letting VS2008 re-create it.

### Apology

Sorry if this was simply stating the obvious.  I know I've been frustrated at times when I've opened a file outside the context of its project only to realize what I want to do requires me to open the project anyway.  Someone new to Visual Studio might not realize the project is sometimes required.

Comment: Thank you, Matt -- yes, it *does* belong to a project, and I *was* opening the containing solution first. So not applicable in this case, but appreciated nonetheless . .